# PostgreSql handle datetime saving differently for different servers

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, ubuntu, npgsql

I have the same code base (asp.net core) and setting for both servers are pretty much the same (since I run the same script for them).

But somehow when saving `Datetime.UtcNow` value to DB, they behave differently (7 hours gap). I also checked `Datetime.UtcNow` by a calling a test API, both servers are the same.

Below is the comparison between both server so far.

Both Server environments

- Os: Ubuntu 22.04
- Postgres: v15

Versus by image:

OS datetime setting

[image]

OS locale setting

[image]

Postgres timezome setting

[image]

Postgres timezone in IDE

[image]

Now from postgres 2 servers

[image]

Query the timegap, from the code, they're just simply `CreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow`

[image: Time gap]

Comment: Where is the 7 hour gap?  You have shown a lot of images here, but none of them seem to include the thing you are complaining about.

Comment: It's automatically when I call `SaveChangeAsync` with EF. I thought it make not much sense to capture a screen from IDE that contain 2 datetime column which have 7 hours gap difference... But I guess I'll add it anyway

Comment: same npgsql version/configuration? It sounds related to [this](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#timestamp-rationalization-and-improvements)

Comment: @JGH yes, same v15 and configuration. If I get it right, the doc above only apply when we read data out of DB. but the case is we have a gap in the DB itself already.

Comment: You haven't specified the Npgsql version.

Comment: I would recommend using NodaTime, OR generating timestamps on the database altogether like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");`

Comment: @ShayRojansky I used `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` ver `6.0.8`

Comment: @EmreBener The thing is... Datetime just works well with other server... I know it works, but I think it's not worth to do that(it's just server problem). Btw, I managed to get rid of it by just take a new server, work out perfectly fine... not sure why since all scripts are the same